# Pull value from table

Tags: javascript

Hello I have the following on a page and I would like to pull the value:  36424. the value will change thus Im trying to create a function that will pull it when i call on the function.

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="cols" border="1" 
     id="OSDataCount" style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-          
    color:#999999;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;border-collapse:collapse;">

    <tr style="color:White;background-color:Black;font-weight:bold;">

        <th scope="col">COUNT(*)</th>

    </tr><tr>

        <td>36424</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

cheers

Comment: is table markup static, ie it is always in 2nd row , 1st col?

Answer (score 2):

### Using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function alertval() {
    var htmlval = $('#OSDataCount tr:eq(1)>td:first').html();
    var textval = $('#OSDataCount tr:eq(1)>td:first').text();
    alert("Val:" + val);
}

</script>
```

See http://api.jquery.com/text/, http://api.jquery.com/html/

### Using raw JavaScript:

```
function alertval() {
    var el = document.getElementById("OSDataCount");
    alert("Val:" + el.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: might wanna mention where he can get jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery:

```
var table = document.getElementById('OSDataCount');
alert(table.rows[1].children[0].innerHTML); // -> 36424
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/369wv/)

Comment: Except instead of `children` I think `cells` is better. Also, instead of `.innerHTML`, `.firstChild.data` might be used.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little detail to previous (correct) answers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var table = document.getElementById('OSDataCount');
    var number = table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
    alert (number);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = document.evaluate('id(OSDataCount)/tr/td', document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE);
```

going off a quick search/reach. Probably won't work, but worth a try.